# Hide admin bar on certain post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-bar

I've got a custom post type - ID `productpopup`- which I want to hide the admin bar for all users *including admin*. The theory behind my function is as follows:

The post type is selected using

```
get_post_type( $post ) == 'productpopup'
```

And then the Admin Bar is hidden using

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

So putting the following in my themes `functions.php` in my mind should work, but it doesn't

```
if ( get_post_type( $post ) == 'productpopup' )
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Wordpress 4.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't hack your Wordpress core. It's overriden after every upgrade (plugins do exist for some reason).

You can solve your problem in this way:

1) Open your `single.php`. 
2) Define

```
<?php 
function hideAdminBar ($post_id)
{
    if (get_post_type ($post_id) == 'post')
    {
        add_filter ('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

        /* For removing the top blank space. */
        echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
            * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
            </style>';
    }
} 
?>
```

3) Inside The Loop, call this function right after the `while` condition. Like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

    <?php hideAdminBar (get_the_ID ()); ?>
    /* etc. */

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I'm not 'hacking' the Wordpress core - that was going in my themes `functions.php` - sorry for confusion!

Comment: It works thanks :) Only thing - it still leaves the space where the admin bar was blank - any ideas how to remove this?

Comment: I modified the function `hideAdminBar()` so that it also prints the required CSS for removing the blank space. 
If sometime I find a more elegant workaround for this I will tell you :)